# AdapterView<ListAdapter>.AdapterDataSetObserver is not resolvable to a type from an AdapterView<ListAdapter> subclass

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm implementing `AdapterView<ListAdapter>` to produce an `AbsListView`-like class I can use with a `CursorAdapter` in a layout.  I'm implementing this because I want to use the handy automatic data update behaviour `CursorAdapter` gives you; additionally, I can reuse the same adapter in a more conventional `ListView` elsewhere in my app.

I'm basing my class heavily on [the Android source for `AbsListView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java).

I'm having trouble with this though: in my own class, also extending `AdapterView<ListAdapter>`, I put this code:

```
class AdapterDataSetObserver extends AdapterView<ListAdapter>.AdapterDataSetObserver {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        //my update code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        super.onInvalidated();
        //my shutdown code here
    }
}
```

Eclipse says "AdapterView.AdapterDataSetObserver cannot be resolved to a type".

I can't see that this is controlled by an import, and clearly since `ListView` can override this class, I would expect to be able to as well.  Why isn't it visible?

Comment: This class seems to be nothing more complex than a `DataSetObserver` so I'm just making one of those instead.  Understanding this visibility problem would be useful, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AdapterView.AdapterDataSetObserver is package private according to the javadoc. See the link here: http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/widget/AdapterView.html .

Thus it will not be visible outside of the package.